# Getting linebreaks stored as \n in database to print out with PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, line-breaks

I imported a CSV into a database I am testing some things with (very new to SQL). While importing I had some trouble with some text fields in a `msg` column which contained linebreaks (phpMyAdmin thought they were new rows I think) so I had to convert all the linebreaks in those columns to \n in the CSV. The importer worked fine after that.

As such I have some text fields in the database which are stored like this:

`Here is an example\nof a field\nwith line breaks`

I am now trying to get these fields to print out on a simple PHP page (very new to this as I said)!

Initially I tried:

```
...
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
    ...
    echo $row['msg'];
    ...
}
...
```

This prints out most fields in my database fine but the ones that contain `\n` are not showing with linebreaks, they're literally just printing out the `\n` as part of the string.

I did some research and tried using the `nl2br();` PHP function:

```
// If I input a string it works fine and outputs <br /> tags
echo nl2br("Here is an example\nof a field\nwith line breaks");

// But when working with the database fields it still doesn't work.
echo nl2br($row['msg']);
```

1. If anyone could help me to get the linebreaks to print out I would be really grateful.
2. I appreciate I am very new to databases and perhaps there is something fundamentally wrong with the way I am processing the data? So likewise if anyone has any suggestions on how I could improve things I'd be really grateful. I'm not sure if `nl2br();` is what I should be using here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expansion of variables and special characers like `\n` only works within quoted strings. You need a different approach for data taken from a database.

Try

```
echo str_replace('\n', '<br>', $row['msg']); // Note use of single quotes
```

Comment: Mate you beat me by 2 secs :) Voting you up and deleting my answer.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! My only concern is whether calling a function for every record that is printed is an efficient way of doing things? Currently what I have is a table with ~33000 records, I'm performing various queries that print out various numbers of records, some results contain a lot of records and some don't. And only a fraction of the 33000 contain an `\n`, probably 500 max. Is it efficient to call `str_replace();` (or `nl2br();` for that matter) for all records, regardless of whether they contain \n? I suppose there's no other way... will it noticeably affect performance?

Comment: I just tried printing out all 33000 records at once and it took about 10 seconds, with the `str_replace();` function. Just `echo`ing the `$row['msg']` out without calling `str_replace();` took about the same time, maybe a second less max.

Comment: str_replace is quite a lightweight function - you shouldn't see much difference. If performance is really a concern it's likely that there are other areas of code that could be optimised.

Comment: @badhorsie The strings contain the character sequence `\n`, not a newline. `nl2br()` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check what is really being stored in the database.  Rather than an end-of-line character (\n, \r or \r\n), it might be storing a literal \ and n.

You can ferret this out by looping over the characters in the string and printing out their underlying codes.

```
$row = array('msg' => "Line 1\nLine2");

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($row['msg']); $i++) {
        echo $row['msg'][$i], "\t", ord($row['msg'][$i]), "\n";
}
```

If the field contains actual newlines, the output of ord() will be 13, 10, or a 13 and 10 consecutively wherever the newlines are supposed to be.  If a literal \and n are present, then you will see 92 and 110.

Comment: I'm getting 92 and 110 :/ I didn't realise there was actually a difference between "end-of-line characters" or literal \ and n characters, my understanding (which it sounds like was wrong) was that if the literal characters were put next to each other they were recognised and interpreted differently, as line breaks! Is there a way I can correct this? And thanks for your help!

Comment: You might want to go back to the CSV import operation itself.  What were you doing to transfer the CSV file's contents into the database?  Were you using fgetcsv() or were you using some other library or custom algorithm?

Comment: Sounds like you might be getting bitten by a mismatch between serialization of line breaks in the generation of the CSV and the interpretation of that serialized form.  There really isn't a stanard for CSV, but RFC 4180 does codify a lot of widespread practice.  If I had to guess, phpMyAdmin is expecting end-of-line characters within a field to be protected by quotes (see item 6 of section 2 in the RFC for example).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Sounds like I need to do a fair bit of investigating.